# sftp width ChrootDirectory get Write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: centos, sftp, chroot

When I try to login sftp with "sftp html84@localhost"
then I get an error "Write failed: Broken pipe"

Here are the sshd_config file of the setting change/add by me

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 3
UseDNS no
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
Match Group sftp_only
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

the user info of html84

```
Login: html84                           Name: html for 84
Directory: /var/www/html84              Shell: /sbin/nologin
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
uid=502(html84) gid=502(html84) groups=502(html84),505(sftp_only)
```

the dir set

```
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 2014-03-17 00:46 /var
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4096 2014-03-17 20:06 /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 2014-03-17 19:56 /var/www/html84
```

Comment: Have you tried following the Arch Wiki? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot

Answer (score 0):

change the permissions of /var/www/html84 and make html84 to be the owner and make sure you are setting the directory to the right group also.

Use chown for that.